# How can I validate on blur with Semantic UI React and React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, semantic-ui-react, react-hook-form

I have a very simple demo react app. It consists of a Semantic UI React `Form` with just one `Input`.

I am trying to use [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com) to validate it on blur. The field is valid only if it contains more than ten characters.

By default the validation fires on submit, but you are supposed to be able to have the form validated on touched, blur or change events by passing in arguments to `useForm`, see [the docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api#useForm).

In my example below the validation still only fires on submit. Why is that, and what can I do to fix it?

```js
//imports

const App = () => {
  const { register, setValue, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur"
  });

  const handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => { setValue(name, value) };

  const onSubmit = (value) => {
    alert("submitted successfully");
    console.log(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    register({ name: "input" }, { required: true, minLength: 10 });
  });

  return (
    <Form className="App" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Input
        name="input"
        className="field"
        placeholder="Type here"
        onChange={handleChange}
        error={!!errors.input}
      ></Input>
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is a CodeSandbox link if that helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-with-semantic-ui-react-z59p2?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to add `trigger` to handleChange after the setValue.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/trigger

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

const App = () => {
  const { register, setValue, handleSubmit, errors, trigger } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur"
  });

  const handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => {
    setValue(name, value);
    trigger(name);
  };

  const onSubmit = (value) => {
    alert("submitted successfully");
    console.log(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    register({ name: "input" }, { required: true, minLength: 10 });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Form className="App" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Input
        name="input"
        className="field"
        placeholder="Type here"
        onChange={handleChange}
        error={!!errors.input}
      ></Input>
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Fork of your CodeSandBox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-with-semantic-ui-react-forked-ho7ut?file=/src/index.js

---

Updated your script to use onBlur instead of onchange:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

const App = () => {
  const { register, setValue, handleSubmit, errors, trigger } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur"
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setValue(e.target.name, e.target.value);
    trigger(e.target.name);
  };

  const onSubmit = (value) => {
    alert("submitted successfully");
    console.log(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    register({ name: "input" }, { required: true, minLength: 10 });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Form className="App" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Input
        name="input"
        className="field"
        placeholder="Type here"
        onBlur={handleChange}
        error={!!errors.input}
      ></Input>
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-with-semantic-ui-react-forked-ho7ut?file=/src/index.js

Comment: That causes it to validate on each keypress, instead of on blur. You could probably use onBlur instead of onChange to fix that.

Comment: @hat updated the answer to reference onBlur as well.